# tensorflow how to non zero values from batched input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

The first index is `None` and batch index,

Here in the following example, batch size is 2 (two rows), and input length is 3

```
In [12]: ar = [[0,1,2],
    ...: [2,0,3]]

In [13]: mask = tf.greater(ar, 0)
    ...: non_zero_array = tf.boolean_mask(ar, mask)

In [14]: non_zero_array.eval(session=sess)
Out[14]: array([1, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
```

I want output of 
`[[1,2], [2,3]]` instead of `[1,2,2,3]` (it will be shape of [None, input_length] )

I'm trying to implement `mask_zero` functionality on my own, because once I give `mask_zero=True` to embedding layer, I can't feed it to dense layer (I'm concatenating other tensors and flatten then feed to dense layer, `Flatten` doesn't accept `mask_zero`)

Below I'm getting `item_average` , which is an average embedding of `prior_ids`, I want to get rid of `0` values from `prior_ids` before getting the embeddings without using the `mask_zero=0`

```
 selected = self.item_embedding_layer(prior_ids)
 embedding_sum = tf.reduce_sum(selected, axis=1)
 non_zero_count =  tf.cast(tf.math.count_nonzero(prior_ids, axis=1), tf.float32)
 item_average = embedding_sum / tf.expand_dims(non_zero_count, axis=1)
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that all rows must have the same number of zeros, otherwise it cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible implementation, which works removing zeros in the last dimension for tensors with any number of dimensions:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def remove_zeros(a):
    a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
    # Mask of selected elements
    mask = tf.not_equal(a, 0)
    # Take the first "row" of mask
    row0 = tf.gather_nd(mask, tf.zeros([tf.rank(mask) - 1], dtype=tf.int32))
    # Count number of non-zeros on last axis
    n = tf.math.count_nonzero(row0)
    # Mask elements
    a_masked = tf.boolean_mask(a, mask)
    # Reshape
    result = tf.reshape(a_masked, tf.concat([tf.shape(a)[:-1], [n]], axis=0))
    return result

# Test
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(remove_zeros([[0, 1, 2],
                                 [2, 0, 3]])))
    # [[1 2]
    #  [2 3]]
    print(sess.run(remove_zeros([[[0, 1, 0], [2, 0, 0], [0, 3, 0]],
                                 [[0, 0, 4], [0, 5, 0], [6, 0, 0]]])))
    # [[[1]
    #   [2]
    #   [3]]
    # 
    #  [[4]
    #   [5]
    #   [6]]]
```

Comment: gracias, especially for the comments!

Comment: now I understand, what you meant in the comments ` all rows must have the same number of zeros,` so this mask_zero is not implementable via `mask` I guess. :(